# Tomcat8 is running but not loading the page

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, tomcat8, ubuntu-server

I had created a new host on the Digital Ocean to host my application. I have installed Tomcat8 and Apache but Tomcat8 is not responding when I try to curl for 8080 port. It just loads and loads but nothing happens.

The host is running on Ubuntu 16.04LTS OS.

This is the Catalina log file

```
        Apr 01, 2018 4:22:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
    Apr 01, 2018 4:22:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2-b12
    Apr 01, 2018 4:22:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
    Apr 01, 2018 4:22:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /var/lib/tomcat8
    Apr 01, 2018 4:22:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/share/tomcat8
    Apr 01, 2018 4:22:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat8/conf/logging.properties
    Apr 01, 2018 4:22:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
    Apr 01, 2018 4:22:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.awt.headless=true
    Apr 01, 2018 4:22:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Xmx128m
    Apr 01, 2018 4:22:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
    Apr 01, 2018 4:22:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
    Apr 01, 2018 4:22:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true
    Apr 01, 2018 4:22:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat8/endorsed
    Apr 01, 2018 4:22:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat8
    Apr 01, 2018 4:22:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat8
    Apr 01, 2018 4:22:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat8-tomcat8-tmp
    Apr 01, 2018 4:22:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    Apr 01, 2018 4:22:15 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
    INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    Apr 01, 2018 4:22:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 1265 ms
    Apr 01, 2018 4:22:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    Apr 01, 2018 4:22:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32 (Ubuntu)
    Apr 01, 2018 4:22:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
    INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat8/Catalina/localhost/docs.xml
    Apr 01, 2018 4:22:16 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
    INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
```

The Netstat output

```
java    3049  tomcat8   52u  IPv4  22541      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

After few hours of debugging, I have restarted the container reinstall Java JDK 8 and that seemed to fixed the problem.